# Работа с веб-приложением из программы

Tags: c#, javascript, java, веб-программирование

Имеется веб-приложение, написанное на Java, и запущенное где-то далеко от меня под Tomcat в виде zul-файла (с технологией его работы и разработки я не знаком).  Я им пользуюсь. Все органы управления - это логин/пароль на входе, кнопки, текстовые поля, комбобоксы, чекбоксы и радиокнопки. Я задумался об автоматизации использования этого веб-приложения. Мне необходимо использовать его из своей программы на C# (мне удобно использовать именно его, но, думаю, что принцип везде одинаков), чтобы не приходилось раз за разом вручную заходить в веб-морду, что-то вроде внешнего модуля. Проблема в том, что никакого интерфейса для взаимодействия с программой у этого веб-приложения нет, и все, к чему я имею доступ - веб морда или код её страницы, содержащий непонятные мне строки внутри JavaScript'а. Куда вообще стоит смотреть? Писать обработчик, который как-то будет просто нажимать нужные кнопки или разбираться с приложением на более низком уровне? Что лучше для этого использовать?

P.S. Прошу прощения, если вопрос сформулирован некорректно, на моем уровне знаний идей для реализации пока нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [selenuima](http://selenium2.ru/docs/webdriver.html)

Comment: На первый взгляд отличное решение, спасибо! Опробую на практике.